# Replace numbers in a word by a char

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like:

```
s ="Question1: a12 is the number of a, 1b is the number of b"
```

Using `x = re.compile('\w+').findall(s)`  I can get

```
['Question1', 'a12', 'is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'a', '1b', 'is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'b']
```

Now I want to replace the number in a word, for example,

- `Question1` -> `Question$`
- `a12`,`1b` -> `a$`,`$b`

I've tried `y = [re.sub(r'\w*\d\w*', '$', x) for w in x]`

but it return the whole word replaced by `$`:

```
['$', '$', 'is', 'the', 'number','of', 'a', '$', 'is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'b']
```

I want to ask if there is a way to replace it  correctly, and if possible, combine finding and replacing in one function.

Comment: Do you want to replace _all_ digits? or only if digits are adjacent by letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adapt the following sample to meet your requirements:

***If the numbers to replace are located only at the end of the words:***

```
import re

s = "Question1: a12 is the number of a, 1b is the number of b, 123"
x = re.compile('\w+').findall(s)
y = [re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])\d+$', '$', w) for w in x]
print(y)
```

Output:

```
['Question$', 'a$', 'is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'a', '1b', 'is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'b', '123']
```

In **one step** (result in string form):

```
import re
s ="Question1: a12 is the number of a, 1b is the number of b, abc1uvf"
pat = re.compile(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])\d+(?=\W)')
print(re.sub(pat, "$", s))
```

Output:

```
Question$: a$ is the number of a, 1b is the number of b, abc1uvf
```

***If the numbers can be located anywhere in the word use:***

```
import re

s = "Question1: a12 is the number of a, 1b is the number of b, 123"
x = re.compile('\w+').findall(s)
y = [re.sub(r'\d+', '$', w) for w in x]
print(y)
```

Output:

```
['Question$', 'a$', 'is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'a', '$b', 'is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'b', '$']
```

Note that `123` is replaced by `$`, if this is not what you want use:

```
import re

s = "Question1: a12 is the number of a, 1b is the number of b, 123"
x = re.compile('\w+').findall(s)
y = [re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])\d+|\d+(?=[a-zA-Z])', '$', w) for w in x]
print(y)
```

Output:

```
['Question$', 'a$', 'is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'a', '$b', 'is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'b', '123']
```

In one step:

```
import re

s = "Question1: a12 is the number of a, 1b is the number of b, 123"
y = re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])\d+|\d+(?=[a-zA-Z])', '$', s)
print(y)
```

Comment: OP required `1b` as `$b`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import re
s ="Question1: a12 is the number of a, 1b is the number of b"
pat = re.compile("[0-9]+")
print(re.sub(pat, "$", s))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:**

- First argument to `re.sub` is the digit that you want to replace.

  `\d+` finds the digits,`+` in that stands for one or more occurances
  of the digit.
- Second argument  takes what to replace pattern with. In this case
  its`'$'`.
- Third argument takes the input string .

This works as you want:

```
import re
s ="Question1: a12 is the number of a, 1b is the number of b"
print(re.sub('\d+', '$', s))
```

**Output:**

```
Question$: a$ is the number of a, $b is the number of b
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
x = ['Question1', 'a12', 'is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'a', '1b', 'is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'b']
y = [re.sub(r'\d+', '$', w) for w in x]
print(y)
```

output:

```
['Question$', 'a$', 'is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'a', '$b', 'is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'b']
```